# Proguard 6.0.3 fails with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: android-studio, android-proguard

After updating to Android Studio 3.2 I can't generate signed APK unless I enforce usage of Proguard 5.3.2 in gradle with:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.2'
    }
}
```

With the new Proguard 6.0.3 the build fails with following error:

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease_beta'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:207)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:268)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:176)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at proguard.evaluation.Stack.getTop(Stack.java:216)
    at proguard.classfile.util.ArrayInitializationMatcher.matchesArrayInitialization(ArrayInitializationMatcher.java:112)
    at proguard.classfile.util.ArrayInitializationReplacer.visitAnyInstruction(ArrayInitializationReplacer.java:118)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitSimpleInstruction(SimplifiedVisitor.java:734)
    at proguard.classfile.instruction.SimpleInstruction.accept(SimpleInstruction.java:218)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:178)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:150)
    at proguard.classfile.util.ArrayInitializationReplacer.visitCodeAttribute(ArrayInitializationReplacer.java:95)
    at proguard.classfile.util.ArrayInitializationReplacer$ArrayInitializationFilter.visitCodeAttribute(ArrayInitializationReplacer.java:196)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:141)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:101)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:93)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:93)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:588)
    at proguard.classfile.util.ArrayInitializationReplacer.visitProgramClass(ArrayInitializationReplacer.java:73)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:430)
    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
    at proguard.ProGuard.introducePrimitiveArrayConstants(ProGuard.java:281)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:262)
    ... 6 more
```

Has anyone encountered similar problem? Is there a way to find out which part of my code causes this "trouble"? I've tried to recreate my proguard rules from scratch (since it might be little bloated over the years) but with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Your fix did not work for me.

In Android Studio 3.2, [desugaring](https://medium.com/@ashish12s3/d8-dexer-and-r8-shrinker-replacement-of-progaurd-bbbb1b65fc36) is enabled by default. This appears to conflict somehow with Proguard. Turning desugaring of by adding

```
android.enableD8=false
android.enableR8=false    
android.enableD8.desugaring=false
```

to my `gradle.properies` file solved the issue for me. But this is no long term solution, at some point we will have to move from Proguard to R8.

Answer (score 1):

gradle3.2 or 3.3 has this problem, you can upgrade to 3.4 or above or downgrade to 3.0

```
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

There may be other versions that I haven't tested
You must delete .gradle and gradle folders, then sync