# How to Solve Proguard Issue - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard, android-r8

I'm trying to Generate APK for my App. But After Building the compiler throws an
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I know what this Error means programatically. But If I disable the `minifyEnabled` to False. Then the APK is generated & the app works Fine.

[I saw a similar question here & tried desugaring to false.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568998/proguard-6-0-3-fails-with-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-1)

But Still it throws `Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

How Can I Solve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in Android Studio. Please go to https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs to find information on how to file a bug.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The fix for me was to add the following to my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}
```

Something in Google Play Services plugin was causing this error for me.

If that doesn't fix it for you, you could also keepnames for anything outside of your app package by adding the following to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepnames class !com.yourpackage.app.** { *; }
```

You might also be able to use this to troubleshoot some more to figure out which class is causing the problem.

Comment: yes it build ok if I set `-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}` but I don't like because it just keeps everything of that library, alternative solutions?

Comment: @user155 I found when I updated to Android Studio 3.4.1, the problem went away and I am able to remove `-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.** {*;}` I beleive in Android Studio 3.4, R8 replaces Proguard as the default code shrinker and obfuscator, which I think fixed this problem.

Comment: @Hayden Campbell I had the same issue than OP and fixed it by simply enabling R8 in gradle.properties (`android.enableR8=true`).